Mockito kotlin does not match the stub eventhough I am using any()
I have the following stub:
        whenever(
            creatorDataApi.getCodingTool(
                ecu = MockitoHelper.anyObject(),
                versionId = MockitoHelper.anyObject(),
                versionNumber = MockitoHelper.anyObject(),
                minorVersionNumber = MockitoHelper.anyObject(),
                variant = MockitoHelper.anyObject(),
                codingToolInternalId = MockitoHelper.anyObject(),
                includeFragments = anyBoolean(),
                includeVcds = anyBoolean(),
                parametrizationId = MockitoHelper.anyObject(),
            )
        ).thenReturn(...)

for a function with this signature:
fun getCodingTool(
        ecu: String,
        variant: String,
        parametrizationId: UUID,
        codingToolInternalId: UUID,
        versionId: UUID? = null,
        versionNumber: Int? = null,
        minorVersionNumber: Int? = null,
        includeVcds: Boolean = true,
        includeFragments: Boolean = true,
    )

creatorDataApi is a mocked object.
I cannot use exact matchers as I do not know the parametrizationId when creating the stub.
I am using this method to match any for non-nullable objects (from ArgumentMatchers.any must not be null):
object MockitoHelper {
fun <T> anyObject(): T {
    Mockito.any<T>()
    return uninitialized()
}
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
   fun <T> uninitialized(): T = null as T
}

And I do not get any exception but the stub will just not match. No matter matchers I use in the stub, the actual call to the mocked api is ALWAYS null.
A few things I tried:

Matching every argument I know when stubbing exactly and only using "anyObject" for parametrizationId
Use mockito's default any()
Use any(CLASS) with the corresponding CLASSes
Checked that the creatorDataApi in the test and in the actual code have the same id

Any more ideas?

There is already a method in Mockito kotlin, which might help you: anyOrNull(). Try with this. But from that part of the code, you wrote it's hard to see if stubbing is the issue or anything else. Try to provide more context.

@mmmatey anyOrNull() actually did the trick when using it for each argument. Thank you!

@mmmatey However when using only one single argument with eq(...) and all others with anyOrNull() the stubbing fails again

What is failing when you are using eq...? You can also debug the unit tests and check in which line is failing, that's how you will be able to narrow the issue down.
